# How to setting up a project in eclipse to program a SPA with JavaEE and AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, jakarta-ee, single-page-application

I'm trying to create a project all day long (in vain) to be able to write an SPA (Single Page Application) for learning purposes with JavaEE and AngularJS but I have no idea how to proceed...
I need in following topics your help:

1. How or which project I have to create/choose in Eclipse to be able to write in **JavaEE**(Backend) and **AngularJS**(Frontend Clientside)
2. What do I need to do this so?
3. I could not find any continue bringing sources in the net like step by step guides in setting up the project and if needed any dependencies which I will need for the project.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me at least in setting up the project so I can start coding with JavaEE and AngularJS

Thanks!

Comment: why angularJS why not latest one

Comment: because I need it at work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to define your learnig criteria.There are number of ways to start learn on this.

On github you can get some boilerplates available.Using this boilerplates you can start easily.
ex. https://github.com/radcortez/javaee7-angular

you can also refer [https://medium.com/@swhp/build-single-page-application-with-java-ee-and-angularjs-4eaacbdfcd][1]

On client side you can create the application using AngularJS,Bootstrap and integrate this application with backend using API.

On server side you can create API either with latest spring boot
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-a-simple-spring-boot-api-from-scratch

or

you can create simple java application using JAX-RS and Jersey.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try your advices out soon and will let you know If it helped me!

Comment: Hey mate, im sorry for replying so late... i just forgot and luckily I can say that I have found a solution by watching a tutorial which was about java ee enterprise applications including these things you mentioned above. My problem was that i had absolutely no idea how to „start“ or setting up a project which combines technologies like java EE and angularJS but now i am good and appreciate your answer!